# How to move the text from left to right using buttons

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Subtext with in the div content and i want that Subtext to be scrollable using right and left buttons(also not to show the scrollbar), Here used the `scroll` method for right and left buttons , while clicking on the right button nothing is happening. Pls help me Thanks in advance

```
const [scrollSubPosition, setScrollSubPosition] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
 document.getElementById('subContent')?.scroll({
  left: scrollSubPosition,
  behavior: 'smooth',
 });
 },[])

const handleSubLeftSlideClick = () => {
 setScrollSubPosition(-Math.max(scrollSubPosition - 100, 0));
};

const handleSubRightSlideClick = () => {
 setScrollSubPosition(Math.max(scrollSubPosition + 100, 500));
};

  <Grid item xs={12}>
     <div style={{display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
                cursor: 'pointer',
              }}
            >
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    marginTop: '0px auto',
                    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
                  }}>
                  <KeyboardArrowLeft onClick={handleLeftSlideClick} />
                </div>
              <div
                id="subContent"
                style={{
                  overflow: 'hidden',
                  width: '220px',
                  letterSpacing: '0.5px',
                  color: styleSubTitleIconColor(index),
                  whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
                }}>
               "List of fruits: apple, orange, papaya, grape, waterMelon, jackFruit"
              </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    marginTop: '0px auto',
                    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
                  }}>
                  <KeyboardArrowRight onClick={handleRightSlideClick}/>
                </div>       
            </div>
          </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you add `console.log(Math.max(scrollSubPosition + 100, 500))` before changing the state in `handleSubRightSlideClick` and add the output to your question?

Comment: this `console.log(Math.max(scrollSubPosition + 100, 500))` is showing as 500